# Control Visibility & trigger animation of an element from separate bound properties

Tags: wpf, datagridtemplatecolumn

I'm trying to build a simple Grid to show a price which needs to show an arrow to indicate increase or decrease in value.

Here the Visibility property works fine showing/hiding the up or down arrow as appropriate. However, if the Ask moves in one direction in subsequent changes, the animation does not fire. Should I try creating another property to trigger the animation? I can do it in code but want to do it in XAML if possible.

Template column definition given below

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Width="40" Text ="{Binding Path=Ask}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Up">
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AskUp}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource blinkAnimation}" Name="upAnimation"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                <Path x:Name="UpArrow" Data="M 0 8 L 4 0 L 8 8 Z" Fill="Green"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Down">
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AskUp}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource blinkAnimation}" Name="downAnimation"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>

                                <Path x:Name="DownArrow" Data="M 0 0 L 4 8 L 8 0 Z" Fill="Red" />
                            </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My animation snippet is

```
    <Window.Resources>
   <Storyboard  x:Key="blinkAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty ="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.125" AutoReverse="True" FillBehavior="Stop" RepeatBehavior="0:0:1">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>

</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: If you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ you'll get it answered quickly